# How do I get text-icu working on Windows?

Tags: windows, haskell

I was able to cabal install `text-icu` without errors.  (I used `--extra-lib-dirs` and `--extra-include-dirs` to point to the `lib` and `include` directories in the binary distribution of icu4c.)

I was also able to build the following simple program that uses `text-icu`, by doing `ghc --make icu.hs`:

```
-- icu.hs
import Data.Text.ICU
main = print $ Locale "tr-TR"
```

No errors or warnings in either of these steps.  But when I try to run the compiled program, `icu.exe`, I get no output at all.  I expected to get a line with `Locale "tr-TR"`, but instead I get nothing -- not even an error or warning.  This remains the case if I try

```
main = do
  print $ Locale "tr-TR"
  print "Done"
```

so using the `text-icu` stuff seems to cause the program to silently fail.  `echo $?` yields `False`.

Does anyone have `text-icu` up and running on Windows?  Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You might try a `print "Start"` as the first expr in `main`, to see whether it's failing on loading, or on the call to `Locale "tr-TR"`.  I can't even get your program to compile: the package installs fine, but on compile it has unresolved references. -optl-L and -optl-l don't help.

Comment: When I add `print "start"` at the beginning, I get the same behavior -- no output at all.

Comment: First one is: libHStext-icu-0.6.3.5.a(text_icu.o):text_icu.c:(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `ucnv_getMaxCharSize_51'

Answer (score 11):

[Stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack) includes a copy of msys2 on Windows, which contains the `pacman` package manager, so we can run:

```
stack exec -- pacman -Sy mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-icu
stack build text-icu
```

Answer (score 5):

I managed it by doing:

- Download the binaries from http://site.icu-project.org/download/56#TOC-ICU4C-Download, specifically http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/56.1/icu4c-56_1-Win32-msvc10.zip.
- Extract the contents of `icu/bin` into the directory `C:\bin` which is on my `%PATH%`. Extract the contents of `icu` into the directory `C:\bin\icu`.
- Use [Stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack) to run `stack ghci text-icu --extra-lib-dirs=c:\bin --extra-include-dirs=c:\bin\icu\include`.
- In GHCi, run `import Data.Text.ICU.Normalize`, then `:set -XOverloadedStrings`, then `normalize None "test"`.
- For each dll that is reported as cannot be found, e.g. `icuuc.dll`, take the `C:\bin\icuuc56.dll` and make a copy at `C:\bin\icuuc.dll`. For me, there were three relevant dlls.

After all that, I can normalise a string in `ghci`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how windows reacts to a missing static dependency.  When the operating system starts a process it looks for static dependencies.   If one is missing, then program is not started.

Use depends.exe to find out what import is missing.  That could be a missing dll or one that is the wrong version.

Depends is available with 
 1. Visual Studio
 2. The Microsoft Platform SDK
 3. Other microsoft packages
 4. http://www.dependencywalker.com

It pretty indispensable when tracking down what is happening in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you should check if there are some DLL missing with cygcheck.check the path and the windows enviroment variables too with it is right. Or try to reinstall following the haskell procedure.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Windows#Tools_for_compilation

good luck