# Haskell on Windows: how to install text-icu?

Tags: haskell-stack

In package.yaml I added text-icu to dependencies

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- text-icu
```

Then I ran `stack build`. There was an error:

```
...
text-icu   > * Missing (or bad) C libraries: icuuc, icuin, icudt
...
```

I tried this answer: [How do I get text-icu working on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127710/how-do-i-get-text-icu-working-on-windows/34542892#34542892) which says:

```
stack exec -- pacman -Sy mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-icu
stack build text-icu
```

However, I got error that `zst` archive format is unrecognized.

According to this issue: https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/1960, I need to upgrade pacman in order to recognize zst format.

I ran: `stack exec -- pacman -Sy pacman`

Then pacman won't start anymore, complaining about some C library headers missing... Need to reinstall stack. Somebody had this issue before, too: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/5300

I'd rather not do this: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/maintainers/msys/

So, how to use text-icu on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround.

The command `stack exec -- pacman -Sy mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-icu -v` displays the following errors:

```
error: could not open file /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git-8.0.0.5906.c9a21571-1-any.pkg.tar.zst: Unrecognized archive format
error: could not open file /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs-10.1.0-3-any.pkg.tar.zst: Unrecognized archive format
error: could not open file /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-icu-67.1-1-any.pkg.tar.zst: Unrecognized archive format
```

So these packages were downloaded by pacman but not installed (because of unrecognizable format). They were saved in folder `C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20180531\var\cache\pacman\pkg`

The workaround is to unpack them and install manually.

In order to unpack `zst` files on Windows you can use e.g. PeaZip program. Once unpacked and having `.tar` extension, they can be installed using command:

`stack exec -- pacman -U /path/to/package/package_name-version.pkg.tar` as described on page https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Additional_commands

In this order (because of dependencies):

1. mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git-8.0.0.5906.c9a21571-1-any.pkg.tar
2. mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs-10.1.0-3-any.pkg.tar
3. mingw-w64-x86_64-icu-67.1-1-any.pkg.tar

In my case it was enough for the program to build.